vs-code java fails to find jar in local repository
I have a maven project that depends on a jar that I have install in my local repository. The jar is generated by the MATLAB compiler SDK; I have a maven archetype that calls the mcr command, and the resulting .jar is installed in my local repository by maven-install-plugin. The pom for the matlab project contains:
<artifactId>disematlab</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>

This generates disematlab/maven-metadata-local.xml:
<metadata>
  <artifactId>disematlab</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <release>2.0</release>
    <versions>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20241103190209</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>

If I now import the dependency in the main project:
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>disematlab</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

the project builds and runs just fine. If I open the project in VS Code, I get
The import org.jeffmandel.disematlab cannot be resolved
diseservlet cannot be resolved to a type

If I go into the pom for disematlab and change the version from 2.0 to 2.1 and save the pom, I immediately see the import and type resolution errors resolve. Mind you, I haven't done mvn install in that directory.
I am running code 1.9.4 on Ubuntu 24.04.1; all extensions are installed on the remote.
Here are my remote extensions:
henoc.svgeditor@2.9.0
redhat.java@1.28.1
visualstudioexptteam.intellicode-api-usage-examples@0.2.8
visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode@1.3.1
vscjava.vscode-java-debug@0.56.2
vscjava.vscode-java-dependency@0.23.5
vscjava.vscode-java-pack@0.25.15
vscjava.vscode-java-test@0.40.1
vscjava.vscode-maven@0.44.0

I've examined the output of all of the extensions for clues without success.

Where does diseservlet mentioned in the error appear?

diseservlet is the entry point in the jar produced by dise_matlab. The MathWorks compiler generates a java class org.jeffmandel.disematlab.:
import org.jeffmandel.disematlab.diseservlet;

I've also found that if I open a new remote browser so that the main project is in one window and the dise_matlab folder is in another, I don't have the problem. So there seems to be some way VS Code is finding the pom for dise_matlaband screwing up the version when looking for the local repository.
